# Creating 2D SwiftyJSON Array in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I am creating a custom iOS keyboard and am trying to create a function that will use a JSON dict to see what symbol to use.

Here is my function:

```
func switchSymbols(option: Int) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            let buttonTag = button.tag
            if (buttonTag > 0 && buttonTag < 100) {
                if let text = symbolsDict?[buttonTag][option].stringValue {
                    print(symbolsDict)
                    button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the factory function to create the lookup dict:

```
func symbolsDictFactory() -> JSON {
    var dict:JSON = [:]

    dict[1][0] = "1"
    dict[1][1] = "["
    dict[2][0] = "2"
    dict[2][1] = "]"

    print(dict)

    return dict
}
```

Unfortunately, this second function produces a blank JSON array.

Little lost. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does fail mean?? A crash, an error, a warning, what's going on??

Comment: Updated answer to describe error.

Comment: I chose JSON because it's easier to create dictionaries using it. And I thought a dictionary would fit well for a lookup table of this kind. Please can you give an example of how a model object, struct or class would be better for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using JSON for data and models within your application. Your internal models should be strongly typed.

In fact, JSON is really of type `[String: Any]` which is not what you need since both the button tag and option values are integers. What you describe in your code is `[Int: [Int: String]]`.  There is nothing wrong with creating a function to return your symbol lookup table. However since the table is constant, it may be simpler to just make it a property of your containing class like this.

```
class View: UIViewController {
  private let titleForButton = [
    1: [0: "1",   1: "["],
    2: [0: "2",   1: "]"],
    //  ...
    99: [0: "", 1: ""]
  ]

  func switchSymbols(option: Int) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
      if let button = view as? UIButton {
        if let title = titleForButton[button.tag]?[option] {
          button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the bounds checking that you had for button.tag being within [1..<100] is unnecessary since the return value for the dictionary lookup is optional anyways and will not set a title for a button tag out of range.